# Adding empty leaf vertices to AVL tree?

Tags: tree, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

I was wondering if it is always possible to add empty leaf vertices to a balanced AVL tree and then colour all the vertices so that there is a correctly structured Red-Black tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very good question. I think the answer is yes. The following is not a complete proof, but I think they indicate that the answer might be true. The worst balanced AVL tree is the Fibonacci tree defined by the following:

```
fib(0) = EmptyLeaf()
fib(1) = Node(fib(0), fib(0))
fib(n) = Node(Fib(n-1), Fib(n-2))
```

This is, upto permutation of left and right child, the unique tree of depth n with the smallest number of node. See for example

[image: Fib(5)]

In such a tree you decide to color the node recursively by the following rules

```
1 - Root is black
2 - for each node n if parent_color is black and n is left child 
    then color = red
    else color = black
```

Then this is a red-black tree. See for example (thanks to [this applet](http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/RedBlack.html)):

[image: Fib red black]

Also there is a note as the bottom of [this page](http://everything2.com/title/Red+Black+Tree) indicating the same.